# Discrete math De Morgan's Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So like if I have a form p^q and say I make p equal giving you cookies and q giving you milk so the sentence is just "Giving you cookies and giving you milk" like when I think about it if I think of the opposite(negation) I just automatically think it's not giving you cookies and not giving you milk but this is wrong but is it really? I mean am I just misunderstanding what opposite/negation means here?

Comment: For "I give you cooking and I give you milk" to be true I must receive cookies *and* milk. If you deny me cookies *or* deny me milk it is false.

Answer (score 1):

**Speedy intro to propositional logic:**

It does seem like you are confused about what negation is. So let's quickly review. First, we need to know what a proposition is. A proposition is something which can be either true or false. Negation is an operation that flips the truth value of a proposition.  In your example, $p$ and $q$ are the propositions. For any proposition $p$, if $p$ is true, then $\neg p$ is false.

**Now, turning to the cookie/milk example:**

Let $p$ = "I gave you cookies"

Let $q$ = "I gave you milk"

Then $r = p \land q$ = "I gave you cookies and I gave you milk"

In your question, you ask if $\neg (p \land q) = \neg p \land \neg q$. This is not true, because if $p =$ True and $q = $ False, then $\neg (p \land q) = $True but $\neg p \land \neg q =$False.

Comment: But here you're saying you didn't give me cookies and milk
If I'm saying p^q where p=I gave you cookies and q=I gave you milk to me the negation means I did not give you cookies and I did not give you milk which is different than what you said. Am I just misunderstanding what a negation is?

Comment: Am I just negating two different statements is that why this doesn't make to sense to me? Is the negation of "I gave you cookies and milk" just "I did NOT give you cookies AND milk" instead of "I did not give you cookies and I did not give you milk"

Comment: Correct, the negation of "I gave you cookies and milk" is "I did not give you both cookies and milk", rather than "I did not give you cookies and I did not give you milk". What demorgan's law says is "I did not give you both cookies and milk" is the same thing as "I did not give you cookies or I did not give you milk".  I will update the answer with variables and logic notation if that helps. Are you a native english speaker? Knowing that may help me craft a helpful answer.

Comment: But again you said "I gave you cookies and milk" that's different compared to "I gave you cookies and I gave you milk" to me, so are you still saying the negation of "I gave you cookies and I gave you milk" is "I did not give you cookies and milk"?

Comment: In what sense do you feel that "I gave you cookies and milk" is different from "I gave you cookies and I gave you milk"?

Comment: Well if you're giving me both of those wouldn't the opposite of that just be you not giving me any of them? Like idk man I think I'm just dumb

Comment: Don't be discouraged! This is a common source of confusion for logic students. I see what you're saying, but negation isn't exactly the same as "opposite". Let's take a step back. Imagine I give you cookies, but I didn't give you milk. If I then said "I just gave you cookies and milk", would that be a true statement, or a false statement?

Comment: Well false right?

Comment: Right, that would be false. Because I did not give you milk. Now what if I said "I did not give you cookies and I did not give you milk" instead. Would that be true or false?

Spoiler: It would be false also. But in your question you suggested that the negation of "I just gave you cookies and milk" is "I did not give you cookies and I did not give you milk". This is wrong because the negation of a false proposition cannot be a false proposition.